# Calling methods from jUnit test

Tags: java, junit

Below is my jUnit test from which I am trying to call `afterPropertiesSet` in my OSGiFramework class. But somehow `getBundlesInformation` method doesn't gets called during that flow.

When I debug my jUnit test, afterPropertiesSet method gets called and then it goes to initializeModelFramework method and then it never goes to getBundlesInformation method.

```
@Test
public void testOSGiFramework() {

    Method method;
    try {
        method = OSGiFramework.class.getDeclaredMethod("afterPropertiesSet", null);
        Object o = method.invoke(new OSGiFramework(), null);

        Assert.assertEquals(false, o instanceof Void);
    }
}
```

Below are the methods in OSGiFramework class-

```
private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

@Override
public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {

    try {
        initializeModelFramework();
    }
}

private void initializeModelFramework() {

    final ScheduledFuture<?> taskHandle = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(
            new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        getBundlesInformation();
                    }catch(Exception ex) {
                        LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, "Exception in OSGiFramework::initializeModelFramework " +ex);
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, 0, 30, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
}

protected static void getBundlesInformation() throws BundleException, Exception {
    System.out.println("Hello");
}
```

Does anyone know what might be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the getBundlesInformation() method is being run on a different thread, so who's to say its not getting run AFTER the assert method or test? Either way, it seems the problem is to do with trying to Junit test a threaded application.

You might want to look into Junit testing with different threads. I've personally never done it but after a quick Google search it seems that its not a very simple tasks and its probably easier to avoid it/break the tests down so they don't have to deal with different threads.

Sorry if this answer wasn't of more use - if someone more experienced sees this please try and give a better answer!

Some quick searches brought me to:

[Unit testing a multithreaded application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111676/unit-testing-a-multithreaded-application)

[Thread behaving strangely in JUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16616590/thread-behaving-strangely-in-junit)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think that since you didn't start the thread(`Runnable` object you defined), so the `run` method will never be executed. You have to start the thread for your `run` method to be executed.

Comment: Are you sure on this? Because that same code is working fine if I am running my application. But if I am invoking through jUnit test, then only it is not working..