# Junit thread not terminate as java main method do

Tags: java, multithreading, junit5, program-entry-point, junit-jupiter

**Example1**
A `junit` test method. This will not print `finally`.

```
@Test
public void junit_Thread() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("run");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                System.out.println("finally");
            }
        }
    }).start();
    System.out.println("end");
}
```

**Example2**
A typical `main` method. This will wait for 3 seconds and print `finally`.

```
public class MainThread {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("run");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    System.out.println("finally");
                }
            }
        }).start();
        System.out.println("main thread exit");
    }
}
```

I want to understand why *Example1* doesn't print `finally` as *Example2* does.

Comment: *Example1 A junit test method. This will not print finally.* - Does it print "run"?

Comment: Does this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16616590/thread-behaving-strangely-in-junit) answer your question?