# testing a synchronous api using junit

Tags: java, android, multithreading, junit

I am trying to test a set of API's from a Android library. One of such api is a synchronous method which returns immediately after called with the status. But internally that method will create few threads to do some background tasks.

Here when I write a junit test case to test this api, my test case calls the api and then ends the tests. I need to make my testcase to wait for sometime till the thread which is created by that api also completes its tasks.

When tried `thread.sleep()` junit pauses the thread, and nothing proceeds.

How do I make my junit testcase to wait until other threads created by the testing method is completed ?

Answer (score 1):

You can test these types of calls by setting a custom background executor. This will cause all threads to be executed on the same thread in order and allow you to use junit to test these actions.

Create a fake executor class like so:

```
public class FakeExecutor implements Executor {
    @Override
    public void execute(Runnable runnable) {
        runnable.run();
    }
}
```

Set your fake executor in your test either in a before call or just at the start of your test:

```
BackgroundExecutor.setExecutor(new FakeExecutor());
```

Comment: FYI, Guava has a `sameThreadExecutor` that does this. http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the replies, but nothing works for me! And I found another thread which answers my question [check here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2836885/junit-terminates-child-threads?rq=1)